# python -m pip install -U pip Errno 11004

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to update pip but I keep getting the following messages:

```
H:\>python -m pip install -U pip
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.con
nection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x031AF3B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.con
nection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x031AF3D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.con
nection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x031AF110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.con
nection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x031AF0B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.con
nection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x031AF170>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pip/
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\a256886\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
```

I have python 3.6.1 installed and when I run pip --version I see pip 9.0.1.

Why I can't update it? Or install any package with pip? What is happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: 9.0.1 is the latest version of pip.  Why are you trying to update it?

Comment: @jwodder I want to install django. I managed to create a virtual enviroment but when I try to install django `pip install django~=1.10.0`

I get the same type of error but with :

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django~=1.10.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django~=1.10.0`

Comment: @G.Doe: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @DavidCullen Could tthis be the problem? I am trying to install it on my work computer. Is any way I can fix it?

Comment: I fixed it!  adding the http:// before the --proxy command   username:password@proxy_url:port

Answer (score 3):

You are behind a proxy. As you discovered, you can pass a proxy to `pip` using the `--proxy` argument:

```
python -m pip install -U pip --proxy http://username:password@proxy_url:port
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade pip --proxy http://username:password@proxy_url:port
```

The documentation is confusing here because it does not mention the requirement to pass the protocol as part of the proxy definition.

Comment: After going through every single answer at https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using , I think I can firmly say that I am not behind a proxy.  Is there anything else that would cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late answer but...

in my case, I was using a network filtering tool (**Little Snitch**) for security, which was specifically blocking outgoing connections from my terminal session/pip.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, using Windows. I noticed that in a cmd or terminal I couldn't even `ping google.com` - internet appeared to be fine and I could access websites through a browser.

Resetting the Winsock catalog solved it for me:

```
netsh Winsock reset
```