# Enviroment Error when I try to install flask-bootstrap

Tags: python, pip

[image]

I've tried several things like checking if I'm behind a proxy restarting web sock and my computer but nothing worked. The command I'm using to install is
`pip install flask-bootstrap` or `pip3 install flask-bootstrap`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python -m pip install -U pip Errno 11004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950994/python-m-pip-install-u-pip-errno-11004)

Comment: No because I am not using a proxy here

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a proxy, you need to pass it to pip with

```
pip install --proxy http://<username>:<password>@<address>:port flask-bootstrap
```

Alternatively (assuming you're using Windows), if you can't access the internet at all through the command line (e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8`) you may need to reset Winsock:

```
netsh Winsock reset
```

Comment: I'm not using a proxy of any kind

Comment: Have you tried resetting Winsock?

Comment: No, but when i ping 8.8.8.8 it works fine all packets delivered and returned none lost

Comment: I also restarted winsock

Comment: Have you checked you're definitely not behind a proxy? Some networks and ISPs make use of them without telling users.

Check https://amibehindaproxy.com/

Comment: Yep it says no proxy server detected

Comment: Are you on a public or corporate network? It could also be that PyPi is blocked. Try visiting https://pypi.org/simple/flask-bootstrap/ in a browser to check if it's accessible.

Comment: No I'm not on a public network and not a corporate also i can access the page without problems

Comment: Also i tried all of the stuff you are telling me and running pip install flask-bootstrap again and it gives me now a new error: Enviroment Error

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? By the way, that package's GitHub repository hasn't been updated since 31st december 2019, it appears to still use Bootstrap version 3 (the current version is 5.2) and its build is failing, so even if you resolve your issue, you may be better just using the official CDN.

Comment: I dont understand what you say about CDN but yes I restarted my computer 2 or 3 times to see if the issue was resolved

Comment: Check the Bootstrap Quick Start: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

Comment: Also, most of what I've told you is exactly what you would have found if you had searched for your error message first.

Comment: Okay and then what? this dosen't make my problem go away

Comment: I've run out of suggestions, try searching online for your error message.